# How do I sort a stacked bar chart in Power BI: sort by another column

Tags: powerbi

I am using 100% Stacked Bar chart and am unable to sort how I want.

Here is a sample dataset.

| person | Item | order bought | rank preferred | Spend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bike | 1 | 1 | 600 |
| 1 | Watch | 2 | 3 | 250 |
| 1 | Tickets | 3 | 2 | 1000 |
| 2 | Bike | 2 | 3 | 100 |
| 2 | Watch | 3 | 2 | 400 |
| 2 | Tickets | 1 | 1 | 650 |

And items:
[image]

My Chart looks like this:
[image]

There are a couple of issues:
1). The person order is 2,1 and I want it sorted 1,2 (less important).
2). The more important place I'm stuck is trying to get the items in the bar to sort by either the order they were bought (order bought) or where they ranked their preference (rank preferred).

When I click on "Item" and try "Sort by Column", it gives me this error (there can't be more than one value in rank preferred for the same value in item):
[image]

I think I know what it's saying - that because the Item has different ranks associated with it, it can't sort, but the ranks are distinct for each person/item combination, so not sure why it doesn't work.

How can I get it to sort the items by rank or order bought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of sorting in PBI. For the first problem to sort person 1 to 2, click the person column and change the datatype to text. This will also bring your bars closer together.

[image]

For the second problem, you have multiple values so PBI doesn't know how to sort it. e.g. Bike has rank preferred of 1 for person 1 but 3 if the person is 2. It needs to be unique in order to sort the column.

Comment: Ok - the first sort worked. Thanks. For the second, the value is unique *per person*, which is at the level the sort takes place. I'm not arguing with you, but frustrated with lack of functionality. I'll mark yours solved unless someone else responds with a magical solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could "trick" PBI into thinking they're different by adding a space or non printable character at the end. Then you could sort how you wanted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Which field should have the appended character? I don't understand how that would help.

Comment: You want to adjust your Item column so it is as follows (without the quotation marks). Note the extra space in the second set. 

"Bike", "Watch", "Tickets", "Bike ", "Watch ", "Tickets "

Comment: I've got hundreds of individual items. I don't think that would work. Thanks for the suggestion though.